# webMethods pub.client.http throws error on 401

Tags: http, exception, http-status-code-404, webmethods

I am using webMethods from the SAG and it seems if the service

```
pub.client.http
```

throws an exception on status code 401 "Unauthorized".

This leads me to the problem that I cannot handle the status code because nothing is written to the pipeline.

```
getLastError
```

does contain the string "Unauthorized" but not the status code.
Except that I do not want to start parsing exception messages...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asked a SAG senior consultant.
This is the normal behavior.
There is no flag which you can set to enforce suppression of this exception...

Answer (score 2):

You *can* suppress the exception and have the HTTP 401 status returned like any other HTTP response.  Go to the IS Admin Extended Settings and set:

```
watt.net.http401.throwException=false
```

Note this is a server-wide setting, so it will affect all your applications/services that use pub.client:http.

Comment: That would have been the answer I was looking for - but fortunately, I don't have to tame webmethods anymore. :-) THX!

Answer (score 1):

The output parameter `header` from the `pub.client.http` call should contain the information you’re after:

> *header*   **Document** Conditional. HTTP response headers.
>
> **Key                    Description**
>
> *lines*                   **Document** Fields in the response header, where key names represent
>                              field names and values represent field values.
>   *status*                 **String** HTTP status code of the response.
>   *statusMessage*   **String** HTTP status message of the response.

See the [webMethods Integration Server Built-In Services Reference](http://techcommunity.softwareag.com/ecosystem/documentation/webmethods/wmsuites/wmsuite9-8/Integration_Server/9-8_Integration_Server_Built-In_Services_Reference.pdf) page 122 for more details.

Comment: First: Thank you for your message! But my problem is that the http method throws an exception. After that there is no header information in the pipeline... I expected what you described... :-)

Comment: I see… well, it would too easy right? :-) Are you sure you are populating the `auth` input document correctly? Or that the target server is actually being reached? Maybe you’re stumbling on some ACL restriction that is causing the exception and it’s not really an _unauthorized_ error from the target url but rather from wM itself?
I don’t have access right now to an installation to test things out, but maybe if you post the full error message we can get some more clues from there…

Comment: Of course! The auth data is incorrect! That is one of my testcases! :-)

Answer (score 0):

According the comment from [@Hugo Ferreira](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30838842/webmethods-pub-client-http-throws-error-on-401#comment49846900_30869181) probably there are ACL restriction whether inside your webMethods environment, or your client URLs.

#### Things you should consider:

1. Do your webMethods server located inside closed environment wherein need to get connected to proxy to get to the outgoing request. Which is likely you can investigate by run web-browser program directly from your wM server towards the URL address (i.e using SSH to run firefox in my case and popup appeared)

   [image: Authentication request popup]
2. The client that your request will go to, have HTTP for authentication requests

#### Solution

To pass this all you need to do is input the `auth` `user/password` or any other auth mechanism i.e kerberos, token, etc. inside the `pub.client:http`

[image: auth pass username/password]

Comment: Please read my question. My problem is not that the authentication fails. How it fails is the problem.